# Ajax changing onclick event image inside the loop

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I was trying to change the Image inside the loop for example If I click the button that is also inside the loop it is perfectly changing the image but other data's that are in the loop was also changing to zero(0). I also add an id to a clickable button to change the image only that I clicked..

This is what iv'e tried:

**HTML**

```
<div class="ult_tabitemname current">
    <div id="dashboard">
        <ul class="slider-20" style="width: 5215%; position: relative; transition-duration: 0.2s; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);">

        <li aria-hidden="false" style="float: left; list-style: none; position: relative; width: 779px;"><a href="#" class="save travel-saved-img-btn" id="img-1058" current-data="saved"><img src="http://myurl.com/temp/wp-content/uploads/SAVED.png"></a><img src="http://myurl.com/temp/wp-content/uploads/1234-1.jpg" class="image-gallery"><input class="mytravel-img-id" img-cat="20" type="hidden" value="1058"></li>

        <li aria-hidden="true" style="float: left; list-style: none; position: relative; width: 779px;"><a href="#" class="save travel-saved-img-btn" id="img-1059" current-data="save"><img src="http://myurl.com/temp/wp-content/uploads/SAVE.png"></a><img src="http://myurl.com/temp/wp-content/uploads/Travel-Personality-FAQ-image-5_09-1.jpg" class="image-gallery"><input class="mytravel-img-id" img-cat="20" type="hidden" value="1059"></li>

         <li aria-hidden="true" style="float: left; list-style: none; position: relative; width: 779px;">\<a href="#" class="save travel-saved-img-btn" id="img-1060" current-data="saved"><img src="http://myurl.com/temp/wp-content/uploads/SAVED.png"></a><img src="http://myurl.com/temp/wp-content/uploads/Travel-Personality-FAQ-image-3_03-1.jpg" class="image-gallery"><input class="mytravel-img-id" img-cat="20" type="hidden" value="1060"></li>

        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Ajax**

```
$('#dashboard').on("click", 'li a.save', function(){

    var img_id      = $('.ult_tabitemname.current li[aria-hidden=false] .mytravel-img-id').val();
    var img_cat     = $('.ult_tabitemname.current li[aria-hidden=false] .mytravel-img-id').attr('img-cat');
    var curr_data   = $('.ult_tabitemname.current li[aria-hidden=false] a.save').attr('current-data');

    $.ajax({
        type    : "POST",
        url     : stats_area_load.ajax_url,
        dataType   : 'json',
        data    : {
            action      : 'update_save_ajax',
            img_id      : img_id,
            img_cat     : img_cat,
            curr_data   : curr_data
        },
        beforeSend: function( response ) {
            //$('.ult_tabitemname.current div#dashboard').html('<div class="loading-wrap"><img src="/wp-includes/images/spinner-2x.gif"><p class="stat-loading">Loading, Please Wait...</p></div>');

        },
        success: function( response ) {

            $('a#img-'+img_id).html('<img src="'+response.get_img_url+'" />');              

        }   

    });             
});
}
```

**PHP**

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_update_save_ajax', 'update_save_ajax', 20 );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_update_save_ajax', 'update_save_ajax', 20 );
function update_save_ajax(){

$img_id     = $_REQUEST['img_id'];
$img_cat    = $_REQUEST['img_cat'];
$curr_data  = $_REQUEST['curr_data'];
$get_curr_uid = get_current_user_id();

$url = get_bloginfo( 'url' );
$uploads = $url . '/wp-content/uploads';
$save = $uploads. '/SAVE.png';
$saved = $uploads. '/SAVED.png';

if($curr_data == 'save'){
    $get_save_url = $saved;
    $curr_data_save = 'saved';
}else{
    $get_save_url = $save;
    $curr_data_save = 'save';
}


$param = array(
    'get_img_url' => $get_save_url,
    'change_curr_data'  => $curr_data_save,
    'get_curr_img_cat'  => $img_cat
);

echo json_encode($param);

die();
}
```

Just to make it more clear this is the sample output.. The first Image if I clicked that violet button it works perfectly and changing the Image.. In the second photo that is the other image also changing to zero.. They are on the loop..
[image: This is the button that I clicked and it is perfectly changing]

[image: This is the other image that are changing to 0]

Comment: where its come this class `.ult_tabitemname.current li[aria-hidden=false] .mytravel-img-id?`

Comment: I think you you should use `this`

Comment: it's unlikely to get the answer with your sparingly provided html. could you be more specific and elaborate?

Comment: ohh sorry. Im using bxslider - http://bxslider.com/ the li class is auto generated by jquery

Comment: I Added some html. please check..

Comment: I also tried to comment out the success response on ajax. but it is still changing the images to zero. any idea about the issue? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure there is only one `li[aria-hidden=false]` within the entire html?

The correct approach should be like finding the unique element in order to retrieve the properties you want, by specifying the immediate [**parent()**](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) of the element, for e.g.

```
$('#dashboard').on("click", 'li > a.save', function(){

    // $( this ).parent() is the immediate parent of 'a.save' which is 'li'
    var img_id      = $( this ).parent().find('.mytravel-img-id').val();
    var img_cat     = $( this ).parent().find('.mytravel-img-id').attr('img-cat');
    var curr_data   = $( this ).attr('current-data');
...
```

See also:

[**.val()**](http://api.jquery.com/val/) `Returns: String or Number or Array`

Description: Get the current value of the **first element** in the set of **matched elements**.

[**.attr( attributeName )**](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) `Returns: String`

Description: Get the value of an attribute for the **first element** in the set of **matched elements**.

Comment: Thank you for helping and with a great explanation!